# Unable to access .ear/lib jars in ear's subdeployments

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Some utility jars which are required by multiple EJBs are in the .ear\lib folder, and these jars should be available for all the EJBs but EJBs can not access classes of lib folder.

This structure was working fine in wildly 10.1.0 but after migrating to 20.0.1, it is not working.

Can someone help me, why lib files are not loaded?
Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing an error?

Comment: Yes, I don't have the stack trace at this moment but the error says: unable to load <Some Class>. This class in the lib folder's utility jar which is used by many EJBs and Resources.